# PYTHON3: How to print out user input string and print it out separated by a comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, input, printing

My current code is:

```
def my_input(): 
    my_string = input("Important ions are: ")
    for i in my_string:
        print(my_string, sep=",")

my_input()
```

So I am trying to write a program, whereby the user is prompted "Important elements are:" and is expected to input:

Na K Ca Mg Mn(all on one line separated by single spaces):

Then, I want my code to print out the following:

```
Important ions are: Na, K, Ca, Mg and Mn
```

Instead, with my current code, I am getting the following output:

```
Na K Ca Mg Mn
Na K Ca Mg Mn
Na K Ca Mg Mn
Na K Ca Mg Mn
Na K Ca Mg Mn
Na K Ca Mg Mn
Na K Ca Mg Mn
Na K Ca Mg Mn
Na K Ca Mg Mn
Na K Ca Mg Mn
Na K Ca Mg Mn
Na K Ca Mg Mn
Na K Ca Mg Mn
```

I am confused as to why/how this is the output printed that many times. I think I get why it is not being separated by a comma, is it because it is treating the input as 1 string? 
And I guess in order to print out my desired output, I'd have to do like

```
print("Important ions are" + my_string)
```

But I know that cannot be correct and then how could I get to print out the input, separated by commas and add an "and" in between as the desired output displayed above??

Answer (score 1):

First, your guess is right, you have to add the string `"Important ions are"` when you print your output.

Besides, you used `'my_string'` (all ions input) in your for-loop, that's why you get 'Na K Ca Mg Mn' printed for multiple times.

What you need will look like this

```
def my_input(): 
    my_string = input("Important ions are: ")
    ions = my_string.split(' ')
    print("Important ions are: ", end='')
    for j, i in enumerate(ions):
        if j == 0:
            print(i, end='')
        if j == (len(ions) - 1):
            print(' and ' + i)
        else:
            print(', ' + i, end='')

my_input()
```

---

Output:

```
# >>> my_input()
# Important ions are: Na K Ca Mg Mn
# Important ions are: Na, Na, K, Ca, Mg and Mn
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative version

```
def my_input(): 
    my_string = input("Important ions are: ")
    ions = my_string.split() # Split input by whitespace characters
    print('Important ions are:', ', '.join(ions))

my_input()
```

- `ions` stored a list of the input ions.
- `', '.join(ions)` returns a string of ions separated by a comma followed by a space.
- `print` is used to print the prefix `Important ions are:` and the joined string. Note that print use a space to separate the given arguments.

---

To show `and` between the last two item, the last item should be printed separately. Here is the updated version.

```
def my_input(): 
    my_string = input("Important ions are: ")
    ions = my_string.split() # Split input by whitespace characters
    print('Important ions are:', ', '.join(ions[:-1]), 'and', ions[-1]))

my_input()
```

- `ions[:-1]`: slicing the `ions` list up to the second last item.
- `ions[-1]`: the last item.

See [slicing on Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

However, the code will produce strange result or errors if only one ion or no ion is entered, respectively. To fix the issue, the length of the `ions` should be assesed:

```
def my_input(): 
    my_string = input("Important ions are: ")
    ions = my_string.split() # Split input by whitespace characters
    if len(ions) > 1:
        print('Important ions are:', ', '.join(ions[:-1]), 'and', ions[-1]))
    elif lrn(ions) == 1:
        print('Important ion is:', ions[0])
    else:
        print('No ions are important')
my_input()
```

Comment: And I think this is the one to go for.

Comment: Yes, but how to add the "and" before the last one?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
import re
def my_input(): 
    my_string = input("Important ions are: ").split()   # storing the input as elements of a list
    w = " ".join(my_string)                                     # joining all the elements in the list  
    print("Important ions are: ", re.sub(" ",", ",w[0:-2]) +'and '+ my_string[-1])  # appending the last element after inserting ', ' and 'and'

my_input()
```

This should give you the output exactly the way you wanted.
The reason why your code prints the input repeatedly is because of this line:

```
 print(my_string, sep=",")
```

It just prints the whole input as many times as there elements in the input. 
Also, sep= "," won't work in loops.